# Como quitar los estilos cuando la condicional if sea falso

Tags: jquery

**Y ahora cómo puedo hacer la funciones de reversa ?, al dar el click**
Quiero que cuando el div cont-campoBusq-relat sea display:block; quiero que quite los estilos que se asignaron cuando le dimos click, la funcion que me gustaria que iciera es dar opacidad primero y luego darle display: none; a cont-campoBusq-relat

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.buscarHMn').click(function () {
            if ($('#cont-campoBusq-relat') != "block") {
               $('#cont-campoBusq-relat').css({display:"block",});
         setTimeout(function(){
      $('#cont-campoBusq').animate({"opacity":"100"});
   }, 1000); 
            } else {
       alert("ELSE");
      }
        });
    });
```

```css
.buscarHMn{
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  background:gray;
  color: white;
}
#cont-campoBusq-relat{
  display: none;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  background:brown;
  color: white;
  
}
#cont-campoBusq{
  display: ;
  width:70px;
  height: 80px;
  background:orange;
  color: white;
  opacity:0;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="buscarHMn">Click</div>
<div id="cont-campoBusq-relat">
    <div id="cont-campoBusq"</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para terceros trabajar con tu codigo esta un poco complicado, por tal motivo te dejo un ejemplo (comentado y sencillo) funcional y trabaja con la misma logica a tu problema.

```
la clave de solucion para este tipo de problemas es:

1- crear una clase extra desde css

2- en base al valor de una variable que se active y desactive esa clase del inciso(1) con los eventos addClass y removeClass
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var num=0;//variable auxiliar 
            $('.buscarHMn').click(function () {
              if(num==0){// atraves de su valor realizamos las modificaciones
                $(this).removeClass('buscarHMn');
                $(this).addClass('nuevaClase');
                num=1;
              }else{
                $(this).removeClass('nuevaClase');
                $(this).addClass('buscarHMn');
                num=0;
              }    
            });
        });
```

```css
    .nuevaClase{
      width:100px;
      height: 100px;
      background:gray;
      color: white;
    }
    .buscarHMn{
      width:100px;
      height: 100px;
      background:red;
      color: black;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="buscarHMn">Click</div>
    <div id="cont-campoBusq-relat">
        <div id="cont-campoBusq"</div>
    </div>
```

ahora resolviendo o almenos tratando de resolver:

la condicion `if ($('#cont-campoBusq-relat') != "block") {` esta mal deberia ser

```
if ($('#cont-campoBusq-relat').css('display') != 'block') {
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.buscarHMn').click(function () {
                if ($('#cont-campoBusq-relat').css('display') != 'block') {// actualmente es display:none, asi que cumple y entrara al cuerpo del if
                   $('#cont-campoBusq-relat').css({display:"block"});
                   setTimeout(function(){
      $('#cont-campoBusq').animate({"opacity":"100"});
   }, 1000); 
                } else {
            $('#cont-campoBusq').animate({"opacity":"0"});//para que desaparesca 
            setTimeout(function(){
     $('#cont-campoBusq-relat').css({display:"none",});//aplicamos none para que pueda ingresar al `if`
  }, 1000); 
       
      }
            });
        });
```

```css
    .buscarHMn{
      width:100px;
      height: 100px;
      background:gray;
      color: white;
    }
    #cont-campoBusq-relat{
      display: none;
      width:100px;
      height: 100px;
      background:brown;
      color: white;
      
    }
    #cont-campoBusq{
      display: ;
      width:70px;
      height: 80px;
      background:orange;
      color: white;
      opacity:0;
      
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="buscarHMn">Click</div>
    <div id="cont-campoBusq-relat">
        <div id="cont-campoBusq"</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: no amigo asi no busco la solucion, esa la conozco yo busco es aprender varios metodos  y quiero aprender es del codigo que mostre

Comment: si ejecutas mi codigo veras que todo esta bien al mostrar pero ahora mi pregunta es como retirarlo de igual manera

Comment: porfa puedes hacer que primero desaparezca por medio de la opacidad el div cont-campoBusq y luego le asinas el display: none a cont-campoBusq-relat, quiero que haa las mismas funciones como cuando aparece pero en este caso de modo inversa

Comment: amigo explicame eso porque estaba mal ???

Comment: ese era el problema el porque no pude avanzar si me explicas porfa

Comment: @Gamez comente mi codigo